# How to test / mock laravel Eloquent objects where object itself contains array items as well as sub-stdClass properties

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, mocking, phpunit

I'm writing unit tests for a class that has both of these occurrences:

`$eloquentobject->sub_property;`

`$eloquentobject['array item'];`

When trying to mock this $eloquentobject like so:

`$mockEloquentObject Mockery::mock('OriginalEloquentClass')->makePartial();`

and trying to set those same array items like so:

`$mockEloquentObject['array item']`

This doesn't work and I don't see how an StdClass can hold both arrays and sub StdClass properties. Is there a way to mock laravel eloquent classes that take care this?

Comment: How do you mean by it doesn't work? Is the class you're mocking an Eloquent model, or an instance of `stdClass`? Eloquent models implement `ArrayAccess` which allows them to be used like an array, and the mock should follow that, otherwise your class should implement `ArrayAccess` too

Comment: When I try to either set the array item using ['array'] = 'something' it fails as it doesn't allow for array assignments on an object.